# how to get proxy ip and port from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, socks

how to get proxy ip and port from text file

Code :

```
import re , urllib , urllib2 , socks , socket
proxys  = open('IPs.txt', 'r')
links  = open('URs.txt', 'r')
#----
P = proxys.readlines()
E = links.readlines()
#----
nm = 0
#----
PROXY = P[nm]
#----
for links in E :
 Post = 'id='+ links
 cj = CookieJar()
 #----
 IP,PORT = PROXY.split(":")
 socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, IP, PORT)
 socket.socket = socks.socksocket
 #----
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
 request = urllib2.Request('https://google.com/', Post)
 # ----------------- ++
 nm+=1
 PROXY = P[nm] 
# ----------------- ++
```

IPs.txt:

```
96.47.156.166:10200
96.47.88.7:14328
97.88.243.210:24598
98.201.217.101:23320
```

Error Here :

```
PROXY = P[0] # = 96.47.156.166:10200 #from the text file 
IP,PORT = PROXY.split(":")

 socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "96.47.156.166", "10200")
```

i need it like this to work :

```
 socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "96.47.156.166", 10200) #withot ""
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `PORT` to an `int`:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, IP, int(PORT))
```

Note that this will raise a `ValueError` if for some whatever reason `PORT` can't be converted, so you may want to catch it.

Depending on the structure of your file, it is most likely that `PORT` will include a `'\n'` in the end. You will need to get rid of it with `strip` before trying to convert it to an `int`.

```
try:
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, IP, int(PORT.strip()))
except ValueError:
    print('Illegal port')
```